# AR Model, Time Series

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I would like to do an ARIMA model of the rate of return first and then one of the unemployment rate. I would then put these into the regression to explain the rate of return.

```r
yield_ts <- ts(Gini_Herfindahl_2$`yield`, start = c(1990, 1), frequency = 12)
unemployment_ts <- ts(Gini_Herfindahl_2$`Unemployment rate`, start = c(1990, 1), frequency = 12)

# install.packages("forecast")
library(forecast)

ar_modell_herfindahl <- auto.arima(yield_ts)

ar_modell_unemployment <- auto.arima(unemployment_ts)

regression <- lm(Gini_Herfindahl_2$`Normierter Herfindahl Index` ~ ar_modell_yield + ar_modell_unemployment)

summary(regression)
```

Comment: Can you please include a reproducible example, i.e. include a sample of data using `dput()` as it makes it easier for others to run your code and help?

Comment: Sure, im so sorry!

Comment: Monthy yield: Normierter Herfindahl Index
0,502119848
0,549150974
0,505295666
0,529390528
0,522166092
0,531578318
0,558430746
0,577869194
0,604728512 and for example some monthly data about unemployment rate: Unemployment rate
5,4
5,3
5,2
5,4
5,4
5,2
5,5
5,7
5,9
5,9

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add more details on which kind of assistance you are looking for? is the code returning an error? is the code just a draft, and you are struggling to correct it?